# awk regex extracting part of url

Tags: regex, awk

I am very new to awk. I have multiple files containing lines similar to

```
xyz msg=(1448783938.658:149777):   uid=505   comm="abc.py"   exe="/install/python/bin
abc msg=(1448783938.658:149777):   uid=506   comm="abc.py"   exe="/install/bio/toolx/bin
abc msg=(1448783938.658:149777):   uid=505   comm="abc.py"   exe="/install/bio/tooly/bin
```

I need two outputs. 
a. One file containing just the uid and exe column (just after /install/) from across all the files
e.g

```
505 python
506 bio
505 bio
```

I can print the exe with

```
awk -F '/' '{ print $3}'
```

but unsure how to print the uid with it.

2. One file containing uid and exe column containing just string following /bio/
   e.g.

   506 toolx

   505 tooly

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following `awk` command:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]="/]+' '{print $5, $10}' file
```

I'm using a set of delimiters. This makes it simple to access the values of interest. However, it works only if the path contains no `<space>`, `=`, `"` and `/`.

Btw, also `sed` can be used for that, this would work regardless of whatever kind of characters are in the path since no delimiter is used:

```
sed -r 's~.*uid=([^[:space:]]+).*exe="/install/([^/]+).*~\1 \2~' file
```

Answer (score 1):

similar `awk` solution

```
$ awk -F" +|[=/]" '{print $5,$11}' bio
505 python
506 bio
505 bio
```

Comment: Note that the `*` when used in a character class has no special meaning. It's just a literal `*`. If you take this into account your answer is the same as my one.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it simple and use the default field delimiter -- then use *sub* or *split* to clean up each field for printing.  Here is the *split* solution.

```
awk '{ split($3, uid, "="); split($5, exe, "/"); print uid[2], exe[3] }'
```

Here's how this was developed:

```
$ echo 'xyz msg=(1448783938.658:149777):   uid=505   comm="abc.py"   exe="/install/python/bin' | awk '{ print $3, $5 }'
uid=505 exe="/install/python/bin
$ echo 'xyz msg=(1448783938.658:149777):   uid=505   comm="abc.py"   exe="/install/python/bin' | awk '{ split($3, uid, "="); print uid[2], $5 }'
505 exe="/install/python/bin
$ echo 'xyz msg=(1448783938.658:149777):   uid=505   comm="abc.py"   exe="/install/python/bin' | awk '{ split($3, uid, "="); split($5, exe, "/"); print uid[2], exe[3] }'
505 python
```

I tried a *sub* based solution first, but that turned out to be both longer and more cryptic than the *split* based solution -- the *split* solution seemed more straightforward. (In the case a *sub* based solution is warranted, perhaps **sed** would be a better candidate language anyway.)

One thing that should be added is some filter to make sure we only process valid lines, which could be as simple as the following:

```
awk '$3 ~ /uid=/ && $5 ~ /exe="\/install\// { split($3, uid, "="); split($5, exe, "/"); print uid[2], exe[3] }'
```

One other thing... If uid and exe fields move around in your file from column to column, you will have to hunt for them using a for loop... which is long enough to turn into a script file like the following:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
{
        u=0
        e=0
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
                if ($i ~ /uid=/)
                        u=i
                else if ($i ~ /exe="\/install\//)
                        e=i
                if (u && e)
                        break
        }
        if (!u || !e)
                next
        split($u, uid,"=")
        split($e, exe, "/")
        print uid[2], exe[3]
}
```

In this case, the leading pattern that checks for validity that we put in the immediately preceding example are embedded in the for loop.